# Basic Auth permission not working in Drupal 8

Tags: rest, postman, basic-authentication, drupal-8

Trying to do a simple article delete with postman against a Drupal REST api. What could be simpler? I'm the administrator and have permission to delete any article. I have "DELETE" method and Basic Auth enabled on the RESTFUL UI module. Yet when I send it via Postman I repeatedly get:

```
{"message": "The 'delete any article content' permission is required."}
```

As administrator I have that permission. When I delete from the Drupal site there is no problem (although it asks for confirmation).

```
http://www.example.com/node/1?_format=hal_json
```

Also I just did a cURL request on the same node using the same methods extracted from Postman "code" button and it works just fine.

```
curl --location --request DELETE 'http://www.example.com/node/1?_format=hal_json' \
--header 'Authorization: Basic YZXfneRWQQEDQ='
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I had a weird situation where the super admin user got an access denied to a custom controller protected by basic auth. But when I tried the same controller with a regular user that had a role with access to the controller everything worked as expected (and took into account my custom permissions). I have no idea why, so this is not an answer per se, but maybe it helps you in the right direction.